# Cannot change dot color despite turtle's colormode()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am studying Python Turtle. I know that the color mode should be 255
in order to use RGB mode.  I also know that the correct format is
`turtle.dot(int,"")`.  But I get the error:

```
TurtleGraphicsError: bad color arguments: None
```

How can I implement RGB?

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import turtle as t
import random

tim = t.Turtle()
t.colormode(255)
# t.colormode(255)

def rndmclr():
    r=random.randrange(255)
    g=random.randrange(255)
    b=random.randrange(255)
    t.pencolor((r,g,b))     

t.speed("fastest")

def tendots():  
    
    for i in range(10):
        t.dot(10,rndmclr())      
        t.penup()
        t.fd(30)
        t.pendown()
        t.fd(0) 

for i in range(10): 
      tendots()
      t.left(90)
      t.penup()
      t.fd(10)
      t.pendown()
      t.left(90)
      tendots()
      t.right(90)
      t.penup()
      t.fd(10)
      t.pendown()
      t.right(90)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary flaw is here:

```
def rndmclr():
    r=random.randrange(255)
    g=random.randrange(255)
    b=random.randrange(255)
    t.pencolor((r,g,b))
 
# ...

    t.dot(10,rndmclr())
```

The `rndmclr()` *sets* the random color when it should *return* the color as it's being used as an argument to `dot()` where it is currently returning `None` as the color to use.  There are other flaws in your program, most significanly the double `import` of turtle that has you using both the *object-oriented* API and the *functional* API which only leads to trouble -- pick one and stick with it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

def rndmclr():
    r = randrange(255)
    g = randrange(255)
    b = randrange(255)

    return (r, g, b)

def tendots():
    for _ in range(10):
        turtle.dot(10, rndmclr())
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

for _ in range(10):
    tendots()

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(90)

    tendots()

    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]